# If $x_n \to x$ in Hilbert space, does $|x_n| \leq C|x|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $x_n \to x$ in a Hilbert space $X$, is it true that $|x_n| \leq C|x|$ for all $n$ for some constant $C$?

It is true for $n$ big enough. But not sure about all $n$.

Comment: You can always choose a $C$ such that this happens for all $n$.

Comment: Also, given $C > 1$, there is always a $n_{0}$ such that $|x_{n}| \leq C|x|$ for all $n \geq n_{0}$.

Comment: @ Vishal: Unless $x=0.$

Comment: The result fails for $x=0$.

Comment: @Vishal: You mean given $C > 1$ right?

Comment: Yeah. One needs to exclude the case $x = 0$.

Comment: Take $C = \frac{1}{2}$ and take $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Jim Sorry, I realised and removed my comment and that made your comment dangling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This need not be true for any $n$, just take a sequence of nonzero $x_n$ such that $x_n \to 0$.  But that's basically the only way it can fail, if $x \neq 0$ then such a $C$ exists.  If you are already convinced that it exists for large enough $n$, i.e., for all $n \geq N$, then observe that there are only finitely many $n$ $(1, 2, \ldots, N-1)$ for which this $C$ might not work.  So choose the largest and increase $C$ as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Lets answer in detail.

Since $x_{n} \to x$, for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there exists a $m$ such that $m \geq n$ implies that $x_{n} \in U$.

Let $U$ be the ball around $x$ of radius $|x|$ (if $x \neq 0$). Then this implies that $|x_{n}| \leq 2|x|$ and now use the idea suggested by Jim to choose a $C$ that works for all $n$.

If $x = 0$, Jim gives a counterexample.